# android 12 + aidl + hal server + app client

Tags: android, service, aidl, hal

Is there any architecture to create a hal service and aidl in android 12?

architecture or steps  to  create aidl service from hals in android 12.

suggest any blogs to understand the aidl architecture creation in the android 12

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.